# How can I execute graphql in java?

Tags: java, json, graphql, commercetools

I have this JSON. How can I execute it to commercetools in java?

```
String myJson = "{  
   "query Sphere":{  
      "products":{  
         "results":{  
            "masterData":{  
               "current":{  
                  "names":"locale(\"en\")"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}";
```

Answer (score 2):

In the [Javadoc for the commercetools JVM SDK](https://commercetools.github.io/commercetools-jvm-sdk/apidocs/overview-summary.html) you find a link to a [graphQL example](https://commercetools.github.io/commercetools-jvm-sdk/apidocs/io/sphere/sdk/meta/GraphQLDocumentation.html).

You implement a `SphereRequest` with the result type as type parameter and in the method `httpRequestIntent` you use the graphQL String as body.

Comment: Could you write an example here? If the link breaks the answer becomes useless.